# Laravel 7 redirect issues

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to redirect with a message to a view ( notification ) after the form is successfully validated / stored and emailed.

Everything Works as expected but unable to redirect after the email is sent. 
Tried redirecting after form validation and it works. But if i call the `store()` and try to redirect after `save()` it does not redirect.

I though maybe something was wrong with my store() function so i created an empty function test() and tried redirecting if like this

```
public function test($request){
    Session::flash('message', 'alert-danger');
    return Redirect::to('/notifications');
}

public function test(){
    Session::flash('message', 'alert-danger');
    return Redirect::to('/notifications');
}
```

It still does not work.

but if redirect from `validator()` it works fine.

I don't know what is wrong. Please help.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Mail\RegistrationMail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Register;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;


class RegisterController extends Controller
{


  protected function store(Request $request){
    $length = 16;
    $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $code = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, $length)), 0, $length);
    $user = new Register();
    $user->fname = request('fname');
    $user->mname = request('mname');
    $user->lname = request('lname');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->kathum_tui = $code;
    $user->created = \Carbon::now();
    $vfname = request('fname');
    $vlname = request('lname');
    $vemail = request('email');
    $url =  URL::temporarySignedRoute('verify', now()->addMinutes(1500), ['fname' => $vfname ,'lname'=> $vlname , 'email'=> $vemail]);
    $user->save();
    Mail::to($user['email'])->send(new RegistrationMail($user,$url));
    Session::flash('message', 'alert-danger');
    return Redirect::to('/notifications');
  }


  protected function validator(Request $request)
  {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:registers'],
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
       $request->validate( [
        'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mname' => ['nullable','string', 'max:255'],
        'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ],
      [
        'fname.required' => 'First Name Cannot be empty!',
        'lname.required' => 'Last Name Cannot be empty!',
        'email.unique' => 'You have not completed the Registration. Please check your email to complete the Registration.',
      ]
    );


  }else{
    $request->validate( [
      'fname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'mname' => ['nullable','string', 'max:255'],
      'lname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
      'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:registers'],
    ],
    [
      'fname.required' => 'First Name Cannot be empty!',
      'lname.required' => 'Last Name Cannot be empty!',
      'email.unique' => 'An account already Exist with this email. Forgot Password',
    ]
    );
    $this->store($request);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try `return redirect('/notifications')->with('message', 'alert-danger');` ?

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it but it wont redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return your store method call in the validator function like as following:

```
return $this->store($request);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But why cant I just call it the way I did ??

Comment: store() method return the result to validator() then validator() proceed the response so we need to return the response in validator().. if we handle all of it in store() then it's work fine.